# Update Query With Joins and Group by Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update

I have the following query and I'm trying to update table1 with the Total amount.
Is there anyway to do this in 1 step?

```
select e.id
     , p.id
     , case  
         when count(distinct e.item) = 1 then 100
         when count(distinct e.item) = 2 then 150
         when count(distinct e.item) = 3 then 200
         when count(distinct e.item) = 4 then 225
         when count(distinct e.item) = 5 then 275
         when count(distinct e.item) = 6 then 325
         when count(distinct e.item) = 7 then 375
         when count(distinct e.item) = 8 then 450
         when count(distinct e.item) = 8 then 470
       end as TotalPay
  from table1 p 
  join table2 e on e.id = '111111'
               and p.id=e.itemid
group by e.id, p.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
   SET total = (SELECT CASE
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 1 THEN 100
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 2 THEN 150
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 3 THEN 200
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 4 THEN 225
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 5 THEN 275
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 6 THEN 325
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 7 THEN 375
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 8 THEN 450
                         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item) = 9 THEN 470
                       END
                  FROM TABLE2 t2
                 WHERE t2.itemid = id
                   AND t2.id = '111111'
              GROUP BY t2.id, t2.itemid)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM TABLE2 t
               WHERE t.itemid = id
                 AND t.id = '111111')
```

- The WHERE clause is necessary, otherwise all the TABLE1 rows will be processed.  Those who don't have related TABLE2 rows, would've been updated to `NULL`
- Oracle (IME, up to 10g) doesn't support JOINs in an UPDATE clause like MySQL & SQL Server -- you have to use a subquery (correlated in this example).  It also doesn't allow you to define a table alias for the table being updated, so when a table alias is omitted like you see in the example -- the column is coming from the table without an alias (the one being updated)

Comment: In the subselect under EXISTS, in the WHERE clause, shouldn't `id` be prefixed with `TABLE1`? And ditto for the other subselect.

Comment: @Andriy M: You can, but the answer already explains that the optimizer see column references not having a table alias to be associated properly.

Comment: I overlooked that bit, shame on me. Sorry.

Comment: FYI, for some reason I didn't have success with leaving the alias out.  It appeared to pull from the wrong table.  And I did have success at assigning an alias on the update table.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
update table1 p 
set TotalPay = 
(
select case  
         when count(distinct e.item) = 1 then 100
         when count(distinct e.item) = 2 then 150
         when count(distinct e.item) = 3 then 200
         when count(distinct e.item) = 4 then 225
         when count(distinct e.item) = 5 then 275
         when count(distinct e.item) = 6 then 325
         when count(distinct e.item) = 7 then 375
         when count(distinct e.item) = 8 then 450
         when count(distinct e.item) = 8 then 470
       end as TotalPay
  from table2 e where p.id=e.itemid
                and e.id = '111111'  
)
```

As has been pointed out in comments, the above will update all rows in table1 even if there is no match in table2 - in which it will set the column to NULL.  To avoid that add a WHERE clause - see OMGPonies's answer.

Comment: Won't that write NULL when there's no matching `e.itemid` record?

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you will have your upvote once I have recovered from the bad memories of the very problem of overwriting with nulls :)